# Installed Ruby gems appear to exist on disk, but can't be found when run or referenced by other gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on my openSUSE Tumbleweed machine and running into some problems.

First, I installed `rvm`:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then I used it to install Ruby 2.3.1:

```
rvm install 2.3.1
rvm use 2.3.1 --default
```

Then I configured `gem` to install to my home directory, not /:

```
$ cat ~/.gemrc
gem: --user-install
```

Then I used `gem` to install bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

That's where I ran into problems. The installation seemed to complete fine:

```
$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.14.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.14.6
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

and I can see it on disk:

```
$ which bundler
```

/home/<me>/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/bundler

```
$ > ls ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/
bin              CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  exe        LICENSE.md  README.md
bundler.gemspec  CONTRIBUTING.md     ISSUES.md  man
CHANGELOG.md     DEVELOPMENT.md      lib        Rakefile
```

But it doesn't actually run, giving a really weird error message:

```
$ bundler -v
/home/<me>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /home/<me>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /home/<me>/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/bundler:22:in `<main>'
```

And sure enough, `gem list` doesn't see it:

```
$ gem list | grep -i bundler | wc -l
0
```

I get a similar problem when trying to run `rails`; it complains that it can't find railties, even though it is clearly installed on disk in ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems, and `gem list` doesn't show it.

What's going on here?

Comment: any luck? iam facing similar issue with docker-sync

Answer (score 0):

First select rvm source by command:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

and then try.

Comment: RVM automatically added that to my bash profile, so it gets done automatically. But doing it manually and trying again produced no change.